# Python global array with multiprocessing

Tags: python, arrays, multithreading, global, multiprocess

Please consider the following code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

myArray = []

def myThread():
    counter = 0
    global myArray
    while True:
        myArray.append(counter)
        time.sleep(1)

counterThread = Process(target=myThread,)
counterThread.start()

while True:
    if len(myArray) > 0:
        print "Success"
    else:
        print ":("
        print myArray   
    time.sleep(1)
```

I am unable to get my success message, and i'm not sure why, I keep receiving `:(` and my terminal printing an empty array. I thought making the array global would mean any changes made at `myThread()` level would be applied?

Comment: But you aren't using threads, you're using processes. You can't share data across processes like that.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks very much, I have just changed from Processes to threads and got it working. If you would submit this as an answer, I will gladly accept

Comment: And threads wouldn't give any speedup. In any case you should rather use Pool.map or similar...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating an second process, which has no access to data of the main process. You can use threading.Thread(target=myThread,), but you has to synchronize the access threading.Lock(), if you are using more than one thread.

You should terminate your thread, when you are finished and wait for the thread with athread.join().

See:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html